# React Hook “useSubscribe” cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

Right now I get `React Hook "useSubscribe" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.` error on my code and try to find a way to make this work.

```
const TodosList = useMemo(() => {
    return lists?.map((list) => {
      return (
        <div key={list._id}>
          {list?.todos?.map((todo) => {

            const commentLoading = useSubscribe('card', todo._id);
            const todos = useFind(
              () =>
                Todos.find(
                  {
                    todo._id,
                  },
                  {sort: {createdAt: 1}},
                ),
              [todo._id, commentLoading()],
            );
  
            return (
              {
                todos.map((todo) => (
                  <Todo key={todo._id} />
                ))
              }
            )
          }
          )}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }, [lists]);
```

I’m getting the error because I have `useSubscribe` and `useFind` inside of `useMemo`.

Instead of doing this, what could I try?

Comment: Is `useFind` returning an array of all todos with the same `id`? If not you can move the `commentLoading` and `useFind` down to the `Todo` component.

Comment: There is not enough information tomo1234. Please make it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).